# jGrid search doesn't work properly when match rule is 'any' and first query has dataUrl

Tags: jqgrid

Scenario:
Use "stype:'select'" for 'Client' column in search popup.

The dataUrl for this column returns `"<select><option value='F'>F</option><option value='O'>O</option></select>"`

Bring up the Search Popup.

First line of the search criteria: **'Client not equal F'**

Second line of search criteria:    '**Amount not equal 300'**

match type:                        **'any'**

Click on Find.

I expect both the records with client type == 'F' to show up but neither do. Looks like the match type is still 'AND' instead of 'OR'.

```
$(function() {
    var mydata = [              
            {id:"1", name:"test",       amount:"200"},
            {id:"2", name:"test2",      amount:"300"},
            {id:"3", name:"F",          amount:"400"},
            {id:"4", name:"test4",      amount:"200"},
            {id:"5", name:"test5",      amount:"300"},
            {id:"6", name:"test6",      amount:"400"},
            {id:"7", name:"test7",      amount:"200"},
            {id:"8", name:"test8",      amount:"300"},
            {id:"9", name:"test9",      amount:"400"},
            {id:"10",name:"test10",     amount:"500"},
            {id:"11",name:"F",          amount:"500"},
            {id:"12",name:"test11",     amount:"500"},
            {id:"13", name:"test",      amount:"200"},
            {id:"14", name:"O",         amount:"200"}
    ];
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({            
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        width: 700,
        colNames:['Inv No','Client', 'Amount'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', width:65, sorttype:'int', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge']}},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100, searchoptions:{dataUrl:'/api/domains/producttypedomain'}},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', sorttype:'int', width:80, align:"right"}
        ],
        rowNum:100, 
        pager: '#pager',            
        height:'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        gridview : true,            
        caption:"Advanced Search Example"
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {
        edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true
    },
    {}, // edit options
    {}, // add options
    {}, //del options
    {multipleSearch:true, overlay:false,  recreateFilter:true} // search options
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified your example and I see that you found a bug in jqGrid. So +1 from me for you.

By the way the same bug still exist in the new version of the new multisearch plugin which is now in the alpha phase (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/jqgrid-filter-module-rewrite/) for more information). The bug can be reproduced if one try to make OR (any) operation of two "not equal" operation. The "not equal" implementation has a bug.

In the current version (with the bug) of jqGrid the searching/filtering follows to execution of the statements like

```
!(parseInt(this.amount,10) == parseInt(200,10)) && !(parseInt(this.amount,10) == parseInt(500,10))
```

in case of operation `((amount<>200)||(amount<>500))`. It is wrong. The "not equal" implementation is buggy in the current version of jqGrid.

I fixed the problem in the source code of jqGrid as following:

1) I added new function `notEquals` defined as

```
this.notEquals=function(f,v,t){
    return self._compareValues(self.equals,f,v,"!==",t);
};
```

and inserted it after the `this.equals` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L483)).

2) I modified the [line 1359](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L1359) of the grid.base.js from

```
'ne':function(queryObj) {return queryObj.not().equals;},
```

to

```
'ne':function(queryObj) {return queryObj.notEquals;},
```

After the fixes the searching works correct. You can see the results [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchTest1.htm) (your original version one can test [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchTest.htm))

In the next time I will post my suggestion in [the trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/) and I hope that Tony Tomov (the developer of jqGrid) will implement the fixes in the jqGrid.

**UPDATED**: How I promised I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-in-both-old-and-new-multisearch-with-not-equal-operation-and-or-any-grouping/#p22136) together with my suggestions to fix the problem.

**UPDATED 2**: The bug is already fixed in the current developer version on the [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). You can see the results [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchTest2.htm) which use new fixed version with even more changes as I suggested in my answer. The new multiselect interface you can see [here](http://ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchTest2New_.htm).