# jqGrid Search Operator Undefined

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm using the built in search functionality with jqGrid and started to get some errors on the server side for the query that runs to perform the search.  I've narrowed it down to the filter params that jqGrid is passing to the server:

```
{
   "groupOp":"AND",
   "rules":[
      {
         "field":"FOO",
         "op":"ge",
         "data":"181"
      },
      {
         "field":"FOO",
         "op":"undefined",
         "data":"196"
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see the search operator in the second object is 'undefined' -- which is odd since there isn't a blank/empty option when choosing the search operators.  Has anyone seen this before?  Is this a known issue?  I can not reproduce it on my end at all so I'm wondering if there is something 'special' my user is doing to cause this.  I'm running jqGrid 3.8.2 with jQuery 1.4.2.

Update:  I am able to reproduce the error in IE 7.  It seems adding a 2nd parameter to a search query results in an undefined operator in that browser.

Update 2:  It seems this was supposed to be fixed in jqGrid 3.6 per the release notes:

> Fix searchFilter in IE7 and IE6 not
>   to return undefined value when more
>   than one field is searched.

It's clearly a bug.  I'm going to close the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem and the workaroung is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/in-multiple-search-second-and-subsequent-ops-are-sent-as-undefined-in-ie6/). The main problem is [the jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6793). As the workaround you should include the following code on your page

```
// we use workaround from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/in-multiple-search-second-and-subsequent-ops-are-sent-as-undefined-in-ie6/
// to fix the bug in the jQuery.clone (see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6793 and
// dscussion on the http://api.jquery.com/clone/
$.event.special.click = {
    setup: function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("ui-search")) {
            $(this).bind("click", jQuery.event.special.click.handler);
        }
        return false;
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $(this).unbind("click", jQuery.event.special.click.handler);
        return false;
    },
    handler: function(event) {
        //$(".ui-searchFilter td.ops select").attr("name", "op");
        $(".ui-searchFilter td.ops select").filter(function () {
            return $(this).css("display") != "none";
        }).attr("name", "op");
    }
};
```

Currently the new MultiSelect plugin are developing which has no such problems (see more information [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/jqgrid-filter-module-rewrite/)). You can download new beta version from [GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid). In my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045726/jgrid-search-doesnt-work-properly-when-match-rule-is-any-and-first-query-has-d/5047479#5047479) I included the demo which used the new plugin.

Comment: @Todd Sharp: You are welcome! The fix had implemented other people (Jiho Han and mkmeyer). I read only about the problem and used the fix also myself. Best regards.