# how to show filtered jqgrid with search toolbar prefilled using single call to retrieve data

Tags: jqgrid

I'm looking for a way to show jqgrid with search toolbar pre-filled and data filtered by this toolbar. I tried code below but this makes two requests to retrieve data.  First request retrieves 
unfiltered data and only second request retrieves proper data.

How to eliminate first request so that filtered data is retrieved and search toolbar is pre-filled immediately ?

```
var grid = $("#grid"),
    notLoaded= true;
grid.jqGrid({
datatype: "json",
mtype: 'POST',
   loadComplete: function() { 
     $("#gs_Name").val('<%= Request.QueryString["Name"] %>');
     if (notLoaded) {
       setTimeout( function() {
         $("#grid")[0].triggerToolbar();
         }, 100 );
       notLoaded = false;
       }
     }
 });
```

**Update**

I tried to fill search toolbar using search criteria passed from query string

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid"),
        urlFilters;
    var namedParameters = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&'),
        parameters = {}, 
        nameAndValue, 
        i; 
    for (i = 0; i < namedParameters.length; i += 1) { 
        nameAndValue = namedParameters[i].split('='); 
        parameters[nameAndValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(nameAndValue[1]); 
        if (nameAndValue[0] === "filters") { 
            urlFilters= decodeURIComponent(nameAndValue[1]); 
        } 
    } 

    grid.jqGrid({
     postData: { filters: urlFilters }, 
     search:true, 
     loadComplete: function() { 
         refreshSearchingToolbar( $(this), 'eq');
         }
     ...
```

Search toolbar is empty if grid is loaded but grid is filtered and find dialog is filled properly.
Search toolbar is also filled if find dialog is opened.

Debugger shows that in refreshSearchingToolbar condition

```
if (typeof (postData.filters) === "string" &&
                        typeof ($grid[0].ftoolbar) === "boolean" && $grid[0].ftoolbar) {
```

if not satisfied: ftoolbar is undefined.
I removed this check but after that got error at line `tagName = control[0].tagName.toUpperCase();` about undefined tagName
How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create jqGrid with `search: true` and `postData: {filters: theFilterAsJSON}` parameters. Look [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4977896/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749723/jqgrid-filtering-records/5750127#5750127) of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6187490/315935) for details.

UPDATED: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6884755/315935) shows how to parse `postData.filters` and fill the fields of the searching toolbar (whenever it's possible) the the corresponding filters.

Comment: thank you very much. It worked. I changed code so that search criteria is passed as json string like jqgrid passes. It contains toolbar search criteria `column1name= value1 AND column2name= value2 AND ...`  like `{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"column1name","op":"eq","data":"value1"},{"field":"column2name","op":"eq","data":"value2"}]}` . How to parse this and pre-fill search toolbar columns with values from this?

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! If I understand your question correct you will find the answer on your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6884755/315935). It shows how to parse `postData.filters` and fill the fields of the searching toolbar (whenever it's possible) the the corresponding filters.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use answer you referenced but if statement in refreshSerching toolbar fails. I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus: If `ftoolbar` property of the DOM of the grid is `undefined` it means that you try to use `refreshSearchingToolbar` *before* you had created the searching toolbar (before `filterToolbar` was called).

Comment: Thnak you very much. Yes, this was the issue.