# jqGrid Advanced Filter - perform custom filter

Tags: jqgrid

```
 var cFilter = {
                "groupOp": "AND",
                "rules":
                    [
                        { "field": "accountname", "op": "eq", "data": "06"} 
                    ]
             };    

$('#jqGrid').setGridParam({
        postData: {
          filters: cFilter 
        }
      });
```

Does this get the filtered data in the jqGrid as I cant seem to get it working?

Comment: Are you triggering a reload after setting the param, if not you will need to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do about the following:

```js
var cFilter = {
        groupOp: "AND",
        rules: [
            { field: "accountname", op: "eq", data: "06"} 
        ]
    };    

$('#jqGrid').setGridParam({
    search: true, // to force searching 
    postData: {
        filters: JSON.stringify(cFilter); 
    }
});
```

Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385) for example for more details.