# JQgrid search string builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jqgrid

Is there any way for search string builder for JQgrid ?
i.e. when I press search button then it should automatically generate the search string for the search critaria provided for the grid.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with search string builder. Probably [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) provide the solution to your problem.

Comment: I want a program that parse the json query generated by the jqgrid and parse into the simple query format of sql.

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. If you need paring of `filters` parameter **on the server side** you will find corresponding code example for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935).