# jqGrid - Filter rows based on data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I would like to filter my jqGrid based on certain cell values. For example, if I have a column named "relevance", an integral score from 0 to 10, I'd like to only display rows where relevance > 5. Is this possible to do with jqGrid?

I don't want the user to have to search for values where relevance > 5 – I want the table to load that way from the start.

Comment: check datatables plugin, it  have this and many other features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `filters` option of `postData` to the filter which you need, set `search: true` option of  jqGrid and trigger `"reloadGrid"`. In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5273385/315935) you will find the corresponding code example.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to do the AJAX call through jqGrid, I want to do it through jQuery. The reason being that I have one AJAX call that retrieves a very big JSON, and I pass each part of that JSON to a different grid, each grid having its own tab. So, if I have five different jqGrids, one for each tab, I don't want to be making five AJAX calls. Is there a way to do this with datatype: 'local'?

Comment: Sorry, my question is, can I do this for a local JSON, i.e. datatype: 'local'?

Comment: @ktm5124: My answer was for the case of `datatype: 'local'`. If you trigger "reloadGrid" the current filter and sorting will be applied. If the approach which I posted will not work in your case, that you filled the grid in the wrong way and you should include the code which shows how you create the grid and how you fill it.